# Is the Embedded Multilayer Equations problem really secure?

Tags: number-theory

In the paper [Embedded Multilayer Equations: a New Hard Problem
for Constructing Post-Quantum Signatures Smaller
than RSA (without Hardness Assumption)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1338.pdf), the author propose a problem he claims to be hard, which is the following: $6268=57240 * x+(1248 * x+(9 * x \bmod 16) \bmod 2053) \bmod 65699$. It seems too simple. But is it really hard? Is there any related problem or related paper that can illustrate its hardness?

Answer (score 2):

WolframAlpha solves it instantly, which is to be expected given that the firt solution is only x=20760, which is very easy to find via bruteforce. But I reckon that the researcher meant that this family of problem was hard, and the time to solve would increase exponentially, not that the specific example he gave was hard, which, with three layers and only one variable, was probably the smallest/easiest example they could give.